# Join two SQL queries by common key

Tags: sql, select

I am trying to join the following queries :

```
Use DB1
SELECT  COUNT(A) AS ItemCount,
                        B
    FROM       
    T
    GROUP BY   
    B, A
```

and this one

```
use DB2
select B, C, D  from E where B=22
```

Now the common key ( here B) is extracted by the first query. If I join the two, i'd rather use it as a dynamical parameter, i.e calculate query 1, get param B, use param B in second query, output all as a table.

Is there a way to join the two queries ?

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  The first query returns two columns, not one column.  Which do you want for the comparison?  In addition, the first query returns multiple *rows*, but the second suggests that you are expecting one value.  Also, you should tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: Please add sample data and schema.

Answer (score 0):

Should be something like this

```
SELECT ItemCount, t2.B, t2.C, t2.D
FROM (
SELECT  COUNT(A) AS ItemCount,
                    B
FROM       DB1.dbo.T
GROUP BY   B, A ) t1
INNER JOIN (
select B, C, D  from E where B=22) t2
ON t1.B = t2.B
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gordon, you are absolutely right, my explain skills are terrible

so I have two queries :

```
Use CarParts

Select count(Parts) as ItemCount, ModelId from Manufacturer group by ModelId, ItemCount

ModelId ItemCount
33      3000
```

I have no idea what modelid refers in terms of a car model, so this is the next query

```
Use Names
Select ModelId, CarModelName, Color from Models where ModelId=33

ModelId CarModelName    Color 
33      whatevermodel   Blue
```

Is there a way to join both queries by ModelId(33), so I get this table below ? :) Thanks

```
ItemCount CarModelName Color  
3000      whatevermodel Blue
```